# Java - return interface without implementing any class

Tags: java, arrays

I have code like this:

```
import java.util.List;
class A{
...
public List<INet4Address> func()
{
// normally I would do smth like this:
// List<INet4Address> list = new new ArrayList<Inet4Address>();
// but I can't because its prohibited by my teacher
}
...
};
```

I mean he prohibited us to use any of public class(in other words I cannot import more class/package than List. Any suggestion how can I return interface implementation?

Comment: Perhaps you could ask your teacher what he expects.

Comment: Well i'm not sure to understand what your teacher is waiting for, but if you canno't import any class, you have to implement yourself the interface List

Comment: Side note - while a semi-colon at the end of a class declaration is *permitted*, it's neither needed nor recommended.

Comment: @Vyncent: Well, "import" isn't the same as "use" - if it were just import that was prohibit, the OP could use `new java.util.ArrayList<>()`...

Comment: @JonSkeet you're right, i didn't thought about this case. I didn't think teacher want to teach how to call directly without import, i don't see the point. I was more in an approach to learn how to implement interface. Nevertheless it's seems there is other import like : INet4Address  . we definitely need a better understanding of what is expected

Comment: You could `return null;` - that's valid and doesn't require any other classes to be imported. Since you haven't stated what the thing that you return should be/do, that's as valid as anything.

Comment: @Vyncent I sure hope this teacher isn't expecting his students to implement the built-in `List` interface.  There are a **lot** of methods that would have to be written.  Maybe they're supposed to define their own `List` interface with just a few basic methods?  Anyway, we definitely need more info or else the poster needs to ask his teacher for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't create an instance of an existing class, your only option is to create an instance of an anonymous class implementing the `List<INet4Address>` interface.

```
public List<INet4Address> func()
{
    return new List<Inet4Address> () {

      public int size()
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
      }

      public boolean isEmpty()
      {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
      }

      ... add implementations of all the methods of the List interface
    };
}
```

Comment: That works.  Of course, no sane teacher would want their students to actually do this.

Comment: @DavidWallace Unless they just learned about anonymous classes.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an anonymous class. It could be a named nested class...

Comment: @JonSkeet for some reason I assumed this wasn't allowed by the teacher either, but I might be wrong.